# AWS - OpsWorks: Error while adding encrypted root volume in Stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-opsworks, amazon-kms

We are receiving below error while registering instance with Encrypted root volume in Opsworks Stack.

====================   ERROR   =================================

> ERROR [agent-installer (29842)]: Failed to register instance with args {:stack_id=>"xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx", :hostname=>"ip-xx-xx-xx-xx", :public_ip=>"xx.xx.xx.xx", :private_ip=>"xx.xx.xx.xx", :rsa_public_key=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n", :rsa_public_key_fingerprint=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", :instance_identity=>{:document=>"{\n  \"devpayProductCodes\" : null,\n  \"marketplaceProductCodes\" : null,\n  \"privateIp\" : \"xx.xx.xx.xx\",\n  \"version\" : \"2017-09-30\",\n  \"instanceId\" : \"i-xxxxxxxxxxxx\",\n  \"billingProducts\" : null,\n  \"instanceType\" : \"t3.medium\",\n  \"availabilityZone\" : \"us-east-1c\",\n  \"kernelId\" : null,\n  \"ramdiskId\" : null,\n  \"accountId\" : \"xxxxxxxxx\",\n  \"architecture\" : \"x86_64\",\n  \"imageId\" : \"ami-xxxxxxxxx\",\n  \"pendingTime\" : \"2018-09-03T04:01:01Z\",\n  \"region\" : \"us-east-1\"\n}", :signature=>"fhHgtIX7rJr0/VrWzBp5f+WqQGiHrWiOFtK2t7truDpkrV15mO6E8pZpXOc8WL/2iXE+0xM7k6wb\nE9FFOkW6/EjCaFfRHjRPsO1ADrlM/Jl/1BhxNNgRH4BwOGM5zPKiQvD4eYRkqQXI9ouFqn33Fpau\nrg/5Z5OQa9b1gzXxSuk="}}: Aws::OpsWorks::Errors::ValidationException -  - /opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20180717045128_4031-20180717045128/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.2.26/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in `call'
>
> /tmp/opsworks-agent-installer.5EJQlpXigyE1oUIo/opsworks-agent-installer/opsworks-agent/bin/opsworks-agent-registration-installer.rb:8:in `'
>
> ERROR [agent-installer (29842)]: Failed to write agent configuration file: Aws::OpsWorks::Errors::ValidationException -  - /opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20180717045128_4031-20180717045128/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.2.26/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in `call'

==================== Error End =================================

We have allowed the permission for Opsworks Role in Encrypted keys. Let us know if we are missing out any other thing.

Comment: Any solutions or resources for references you got till now?